# \backmatter seems to disable indexing

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm trying to collect all my "X, see Y" index entries in one place, for ease of maintenance. The logical place for index entries unassociated with any specific page seemed to be my "index.tex" file, right before I called `\printindex`. So I have this:

### mwe.tex

```
\documentclass[ebook,10pt,oneside,final]{memoir}

% support for cross-references (must come before imakeidx)
\usepackage{hyperref}

% support for indexing
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=book2,intoc,columns=2]

\begin{document}

Hello world.
\index[book2]{hello world}

\backmatter
\include{index}

\end{document}
```

### index.tex

```
\index[book2]{world!hello|see{hello world}}
\printindex[book2]
```

---

The "world, hello" entry does not show up in `book2.idx`.

Experimentation shows that if I remove the `\backmatter` command, then the index entry does show up. Does `\backmatter` have the side-effect of suppressing new index entries? Should I be using something else if all I want is a division between page-numbering schemes?

I feel like I can work around this issue by just making a `see-also.tex` containing my index entries and including it *before* the `\backmatter` command, but I'd still like to understand the root cause, if I can.

Comment: This should probably be tagged `back-matter` but that tag doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Here's a shorter MWE: `\documentclass{book} \usepackage{imakeidx} \makeindex \begin{document} Hello world.  \index{hello world} \cleardoublepage \index{test} \printindex \end{document}` I suspect it's due to the delayed write being deferred until after the `.idx` file has been closed. (`\backmatter` performs `\cleardoublepage`)